# Macro incorrectly deleting table lines

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro that I run to add lines to a table, this information comes from a sql database.

My problem is, when I step through the macro it works absolutely fine and does exactly what it's supposed to. However, when I run the macro, lines go missing.

Anyone experienced something similar/any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Tom

```
Sub BOMpart()
Dim NoRow, SupRow, i, j, k, h As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

NoCol = Range("Data").Columns.Count

' Reset Data Range
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Range("Data").Rows.Count > 1 Or Range("Data").Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
    Range("Data").Delete
End If
If Range("Supplier").Rows.Count > 1 Or Range("Supplier").Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
    Range("Supplier").Delete
End If
If NoCol > 3 Then
    For a = NoCol To 4 Step -1
        Range("Data").Columns(a).Delete
    Next a
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Initiate level counter
j = 1
k = 1

' Set up Level 1 BOM
part = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter top level part number:")
Range("Supplier").Cells(1, 1) = part
SupRow = Range("Supplier").Rows.Count

If part = False Then
    End
Else
    Sheets("BOMs").ListObjects( _
        "BOMs").Range. _
        AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("BOMs").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Columns(1)
    Range("BOMs").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Supplier").Cells(SupRow + 1, 1)

End If

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

' Part Description and FAI
NoRow = Range("Data").Rows.Count

For i = 1 To NoRow
    part = Range("Data").Cells(i, k)
    Sheets("Inventory").ListObjects( _
        "Inventory").Range. _
        AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("Inventory").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 1)
    Range("Inventory").Columns(72).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 2)
Next i


' Input additional Levels
Do Until Range("Data").Rows.Count = Application.CountIf(Range("Data").Columns(k), "N/A")

NoRow = Range("Data").Rows.Count
NoCol = Range("Data").Columns.Count

j = j + 1
Sheets("BOM Data").Cells(1, NoCol + 1) = "Level " & j & " Pt No:"
Sheets("BOM Data").Cells(1, NoCol + 2) = "Level " & j & " Pt Desc."
Sheets("BOM Data").Cells(1, NoCol + 3) = "Level " & j & " FAI Req"
k = k + 3
On Error Resume Next
For i = NoRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("Data").Cells(i, k - 3) <> "N/A" Then
        SupRow = Range("Supplier").Rows.Count

        part = Range("Data").Cells(i, k - 3)

        Sheets("BOMs").ListObjects( _
            "BOMs").Range. _
            AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part, Operator:=xlAnd
        nopart = Range("BOMs").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count
        If nopart > 0 Then
            Rows(i + 2).Resize(nopart - 1).Insert
            Range("Data").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, k - 1)).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + nopart - 1, k - 1))
            Range("BOMs").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Cells(i, k)
            Range("BOMs").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Supplier").Cells(SupRow + 1, 1)
        Else
            Range("Data").Cells(i, k) = "N/A"
        End If
    Else
        Range("Data").Cells(i, k) = "N/A"
    End If
    nopart = 0
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

NoRow = Range("Data").Rows.Count
For i = 1 To NoRow
    If Range("Data").Cells(i, k) <> "N/A" Then
        part = Range("Data").Cells(i, k)
        Sheets("Inventory").ListObjects( _
            "Inventory").Range. _
        AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part, Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("Inventory").Columns(4).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 1)
        Range("Inventory").Columns(72).SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 2)
    Else
        Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 1) = "N/A"
        Range("Data").Cells(i, k + 2) = "N/A"
    End If
Next i

Loop

'Tidy Up
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Range("Data")
    .Columns(NoCol + 3).Delete
    .Columns(NoCol + 2).Delete
    .Columns(NoCol + 1).Delete
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Formatting

With Range("Data")
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With


Sheets("Counter").Cells(1, 2) = 1
MsgBox "Done!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have added the code, I'm afraid it is pretty long and I can't isolate it to just one segment. Thanks, Tom

Comment: I would start by qualifying every single `Range()` reference with a specific worksheet.  That's often a source of problems.

Comment: Hi Tim,
I have done all of this using the option explicit statement and I am still faced with the same issue.
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Option Explicit forces you to declare all your variables. That's different from qualifying your ranges. What I mean is that instead of having (e.g.) `Range("A1")` you should use `ws.Range("A1")` where `ws` is a variable representing a specific worksheet.  Unqualified Range() calls in a general code module always point to whichever sheet is active at the time - this can be tricky to track and means you have to activate the sheet you want to work with, which is usually unnecessary and slows down your code.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Was unaware of that. Think I've fixed it though. Found poor error handling on the resizing of the table was probably causing it. Added another if conditional to stop this and has been working fine since. Will update my code with this though as wel. Thanks a lot. Tom

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define the type of each variable in VBA even if they are on the same line. So right now your `h` variable is actually the only one defined as an integer. Not sure if this is causing your problem, but it should be fixed.

I see that in your **Tidy Up** section, you delete columns adjacent to the "Data" range, yet the "Data" range was potentially deleted in a previous conditional. I could see how this might cause unexpected deletes.

It would help if you tell us where the code is breaking.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try to declare all the variables. The Tidy Up and deleting the Data Range first serves two purposes. As this is an automatic script which runs off of a sql database, it first resets itself, it then adds levels depending on how many it finds. It stops doing this once it adds a level but has nothing to populate it with. This is why the tidy up section is there, as this gets rid of the level that is unpopulated.

Comment: I have now used an option explicit statement to ensure all variables are defined, but I am still experiencing the same problem.